Is there a way to paralellize db operations with Node.js, that I can use ES6 + typescript on?
I want to make a CRON job that handles some db operations by making X threads and assigning a range of indexes in the db that each thread will handle.
I've tried using worker-threads but it has no support for ES6 imports, is there an alternative to this? I cannot import stuff like Prisma Client because it won't work with require()

' I cannot import stuff like Prisma Client because it won't work with require()'

from this do you mean , you are not able to use prisma in nodejs .

@VeerPratap im not able to use it in a commonjs environment, worker threads force me to use require()

You absolutely don't need multiple threads for running parallel database operations from nodejs.

@Bergi how could that be done then?

@DuduDudu Just start multiple asynchronous operations without waiting for each other

@Bergi that makes sense, lol, thank you. could you explain why anyone would need server Workers then? if you can just start multiple async without await

Not for making database connections or other network requests. But see https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads
